# Why the beautifulsoup code part returns NaN?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Any idea why the following returns NaN?

```
postDate,postUser, postVerifiedUser, 
postLikes,postVerifiedTags,postUnverifiedTags, 
postComment,postLocation, postAccessibility,postLink
```

The full code link is here https://github.com/kitsamho/Instagram_Scraper_Graph/blob/master/InstagramScraper.ipynb

Comment: The code you posted does not appear in the file you linked. We'll also need to see the relevant HTML from the site you're trying to scrape

Comment: Your post need improvement. Take a tour:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: beautifulsoup doesn't return nan

Answer (score 1):

I remember I run with your problem long time ago, the problem was that some websites data works only when JavaScript code load, and using beautifulsoup don't wait to the JavaScript code to load. The solution I come up with was this.

Use HTMLSessions,

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
```

Then you define the session

```
session = HTMLSession()
```

Then you apply BeautifulSoup

```
URL = "Link to scrape, https://...."
page = session.get(URL).content

soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
data = soup.find_all('p') # All the <p> tags
```